# Unexpected behaviour of animated elements

Tags: javascript, animation, gsap

Here is [Codepen5](https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/vrOvKR?editors=1010) of my animation.
 As you can see there is something wrong with "entering" animation of the last element in array of items.

Almost the same code worked great with four elements - [Codepen4](https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/KeprjL). Problems occurred after I've added one more item to menu and following code to reorganize expanded items on screens smaller than 1300px;

```
if (winsize < 1600) {
    if (i === 0) {
        $(this.items[i]).css('transform', `translate(${ winsize/2 - 1.5*grow}px, 170px)`)
    }
    if(i === this.items.length - 1) {
        $(this.items[i]).css('transform', `translate(${ -1*(winsize/2 - 1.5*grow)}px, 170px)`)
    }
}
```

(lines 43 - 51)

Also made a change in line 31:`const quarter = winsize / 4;` to

```
const quarter = winsize / 5;
```

Will appreciate any ideas about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it glitches when you change position by translate after starting animation.
So.. better be changing topPos and leftPos value **before** using TweenMax.to function.

Instead of this

```
        //move blue and purple to the second row
            if (winsize < 1600) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    $(this.items[i]).css('transform', `translate(${ winsize/2 - 1.5*grow}px, 170px)`)
                }
                if(i === this.items.length - 1) {

                $(this.items[i]).css('transform', `translate(${ -1*(winsize/2 - 1.5*grow)}px, 170px)`)
                }
            }
        }
```

Change topPos and leftPos **before** TweenMax.to

```
           //move blue and purple to the second row
            if (winsize < 1600) {
                if(i === 0) {
                  topPos = topPos + 170;
                  rightPos = rightPos - (winsize/2 - 1.5*grow);
                }
                if(i === this.items.length - 1) {
                  topPos = topPos + 170;
                  rightPos = rightPos + (winsize/2 - 1.5*grow)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! Such an obvious solution but for some reason, I made all overcomplicated.

Comment: @IP_  playing with jQuery has lots of fun.. but once you messed it up, you screwed up!! I recommend you to take a *backup* before you doing something with high risk.